# Getting the start date and end date of all weeks by giving the year

Tags: oracle10g

I have a query which displays a set of 52 numbers along with the respective dates of that week

```
         SELECT kkk, TO_CHAR (start_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY'),
              TO_CHAR (start_date + 6, 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS end_day
            FROM (SELECT       TRUNC (TRUNC (TO_DATE ('2014', 'YYYY'), 'YYYY') + 1 * 7,
                        'IW'
                       )
               - 1 start_date,
               ROWNUM AS kkk
          FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= 52);
```

but the problem with this query is that I am only getting the first week dates but not for the next consecutive weeks.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```
SELECT kkk,
       TO_CHAR(start_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY') start_date, 
       TO_CHAR(start_date + 6, 'DD-MON-YYYY') end_day
FROM(
     SELECT TRUNC(Trunc(to_date('2014', 'YYYY'),'YYYY')+ LEVEL * 7,'IW')-1 start_date , 
            ROWNUM kkk
     FROM duaL
     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 52
     );
```

Instead of `ROWNUM` you can also use `LEVEL`, Like,

```
 SELECT TRUNC(Trunc(to_date('2014', 'YYYY'),'YYYY')+ LEVEL * 7,'IW')-1 start_date , 
        level kkk
 FROM duaL
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 52
```

Comment: There is one problem coming in this, In this query the first week of 2013 is from 30 dec to 5th jan but this query shows from 6th jan to 12th jan

Comment: @user2357418, No, 1st week means that, the week starting from `SUN`. it's `06 Jan`. `Dec 30` to `JAN 5` is the last week of the year 2013.

Comment: But I wanted the first week of 2013 as dated from 30 dec to 5th jan. Is it possible because I tried a lot but couldn't get it

Comment: @user2357418, if you rewrite your query to start the date with `30-DEC-2013`, then your 52th week date is `22-DEC-2013`, means `29-DEC-13` will be skipped as we are restricting the count to 52. Is this actually you needed?

Comment: No no I needed the first week of 2014 as the days remaining from 2013's last week plus the remaining days of 2014. As for the count 52, let it be there.